# PhpSpreadsheet how to get data from cells?

Tags: php, excel

I'm really noob in programing...
I need PHP script to make a changes in xmls file using PhpSpreadsheet.

1. To Data from column B "First Name" add data from column C "Second Name" and write in column "D" together
2. From column E "SKU" where data have 9 numbers, take only 6 numbers and put to column F

My code

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';


use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();

$spreadsheet = $reader->load("hello world.xlsx");

$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

$sheet->setCellValue('D2', '=(B2& " " &C2)');
//how to do this in loop for all cells?

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('hello world.xlsx');
```

Comment: You describe what you _need_ and the code you're currently running. But you do not say what does / does not work exactly as expected. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: 1) I don't know how to make loop for all rows, $sheet->setCellValue('D2', '=(B2& " " &C2)'); it is working only for D2 cells not for D3 D4 D5 etc

Comment: 2) I don`t have idea how to write a code for my second requirements